# How to Clone a Windows 7 Partition to a new Hard Drive?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, clone

I just bought a ssd drive and I have 2 partitions. 1 is for work and one is for personal. I did a fresh install for my personal partition. However for work I want to make a clone(it would be a huge pain to setup everything again) of it on my ssd drive.

Original Drive

1 Tb seagate hard drive and has my 100gb work partition with windows 7 on it.

I want to now take that partition and put it on a partition of the ssd drive.

I tried to use

Acronis Disk Director to make a copy of it and I tried DriveImage XML to do a clone of it and I get the same result both times.

The cloning finishes and I was unable to acess my work windows 7. I used "EasyBCD 2.1.2" to hookup my computer so it can handle dual boot(my fresh windows 7 and my work windows 7).

I loaded into my work windows 7 partition and it comes to the login screen and everything is all good till I try to log in.

I get a screen that goes "personalizing settings". After like 5 minutes it goes to another screen with a dialog box in the top left corner.

"setting up personalized settings for: web platform customizations".

After 45mins it is still on this screen.

I don't know why this is happening.

Edit

I should mention that I can log into my work partition under safe mode. It does not run into that problem but it comes up with a message saying the "profile is broken....."

Answer (score 2):

This effect proably comes from the setting of the mounted devices. There is a registry entry that defines which drive letter is assigned to which unique drive ID. So basically if you copy a windows installation to a new drive and start from there it will still try to use original drive as C: and so on. Google for "mounted devices registry" for more info. I used to copy windows including any hidden and system files with total commander, used the free EruNT to copy registry files, load the system registry with regedt32 (it'S now the same as regedit), edit the mounted devices key by renaming the appropriate keys and voila I had a bootable working installation without any partition cloning tools. I don't know if it still works with Windows7+.